# JQuery DataTables server-side pagination

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pagination, datatables

In my web-app I'm using JQuery [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) plug-in to show data retrieved from database.

I'm currently using client-side pagination, but data in my tables are growing a lot, and loading in ASP.NET pages is now becoming a bit slow. So I was planning to switch to server-side pagination.

I know that DataTables plug-in supports it, but searching around I haven't found notting clear about implementing it.

My main doubt is: if I implement pagination on server-side I also have to implement ordering, or I can delegate it to client-side?

Have you ever experienced this?

**NOTE** I'm using Linq to SQL to connect to my DB

Comment: How do you connect to your database? Linq to SQL, EF, NH, DataSet?

Comment: @Jupaol I'm using Linq to SQL

Answer (score 10):

The existing answers *might* apply to an old version of dataTable, but current versions (I am using 1.10+) pass the start record and length so anything suggesting `pageNo * pageSize` is going to give incorrect results.

### First simple "manual" approach

The accepted answer was also very complicated for what I wanted to do so, after some debugging, I found that the page size and start record are simply passed as Http `Request` values named `start` and `length`. The text search is passed as `search[value]` The sort order is passed in a member named `order[0][column]` and the sort direction in `order[0][dir]` etc.

The basic code I used to sort and filter looks like this:

Get the paging, sorting and filtering values from the HTTP Request object:

```
int startRec = 0;
int.TryParse(Request["start"], out startRec);
int pageSize = 10;
int.TryParse(Request["length"], out pageSize);
var search = Request["search[value]"];
var order = Request["order[0][column]"];
var direction = Request["order[0][dir]"];

var query = this._dataStore.Records.AsQueryable();
```

Apply (case insensitive) search first:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Label.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));
}
```

Then apply any sorting:

```
switch (order)
{
    // My id column
    case "0":
        query = (direction == "desc") ? query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id) : query.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        break;
    // My label column
    case "1":
        query = (direction == "desc") ? query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Label) : query.OrderBy(x => x.Label);
        break;
}
```

Finally apply the paging:

```
query = query.Skip(startRec).Take(pageSize);
```

The correct records are now ready to return.

**Update (using "Datatables.net for MVC5")**

Once I understood the basics of server-side dataTables, it was time to start looking for existing plugins/utils to simplify this code. The most appropriate one I have found so far, for MVC 5, is the [Datatables.net for MVC5](http://www.nuget.org/packages/datatables.mvc5/) nuget package.

1. Install the NuGet Package
2. Change the controller Action to use a `DataTablesBinder` to provide a IDataTablesRequest interface

e.g.

```
 public JsonResult Table([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestmodel)
```

3. Apply any search filter first:

e.g.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestmodel.Search.Value))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.CompanyTypeName.Contains(requestmodel.Search.Value) || x.CompanyTypeDescription.Contains(requestmodel.Search.Value));
}
```

4. The apply any sorting:

e.g.

```
foreach (var sort in requestmodel.Columns.GetSortedColumns())
{
    switch (sort.Name)
    {
        case "CompanyTypeDescription":
            query = sort.SortDirection == Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant ? query.OrderBy(x => x.CompanyTypeDescription) : query.OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyTypeDescription);
            break;
        case "CompanyTypeName":
        default:
            query = sort.SortDirection == Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant ? query.OrderBy(x => x.CompanyTypeName) : query.OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyTypeName);
            break;
    }
}
```

5. Then apply the paging using `Skip` and `Take` as before:

e.g.

```
var result = query.Skip(requestmodel.Start).Take(requestmodel.Length).Select(x => new { x.CompanyTypeName, x.CompanyTypeDescription });
```

6. And finally return the JSON result using the `DataTablesResponse` object:

e.g.

```
return Json(new DataTablesResponse(requestmodel.Draw, result, query.Count(), base.RefSureContext.CompanyType.Count()), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This simplified all the searching, sorting & paging into a nice easy to repeat pattern.

The [documentation for the addin is here](https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.mvc).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using LINQ to SQL, paginate is really easy:

```
var c = new MyDataContext("your string");

c.Employees.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

This code will effectively paginate on the server

I haven't used the *DataTables* jQuery plug-in, but I assume you use AJAX to get the data (since you are not using MVC), so simply send as parameters the current page index, and the number of rows per page - page size, and that's it

To fulfill the requirement, you would need to order your query on the server as well, so you would need to send the order criteria to the server and apply the order.

To order on the server based on a `string`, check the following question:

[Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41244/1268570)

Comment: jQuery `dataTable` automatically sends the *start record* and page size, and not a *page number*. The sorting is send as a collection of indexed column name/values. This answer is misleading for `dataTable` use and only applies where simple manual paging/sorting is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but this is worth sharing :)

```
Employees
    .OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortOrder)
    .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: jQuery `dataTable` sends the *start record*, and not a *page number*. Also the sort order is sent in a far more complicated way. This answer is both incorrect for the question asked and misleading to those that find it.